# Creating a static unordered_set from keys of a static unordered_map

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, static-variables

I'm writing a front-end for a compiler and currently working on implementing punctuator scanning functionality. I've got a `Punctuator` class that I'd like to use to represent punctuators from the input source file in my tokens, and additionally it'll be home to some static helper methods for scanning. Here is punctuator.h:

```
#ifndef PUNCTUATOR_H_
#define PUNCTUATOR_H_

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

#include "reserved_component.h"

enum class PunctuatorEnum {
    OPEN_BRACE,
    CLOSE_BRACE,
    TERMINATOR,
    EQUAL,
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVIDE,
};

class Punctuator : public ReservedComponent {
public:
    Punctuator(std::string lexeme);
    Punctuator(Punctuator&& punctuator);

    static bool IsPunctuator(std::string buffer);
    static PunctuatorEnum ForLexeme(std::string buffer);

private:
    PunctuatorEnum punctuator_enum;
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, PunctuatorEnum> dictionary;
};

#endif // PUNCTUATOR_H_
```

As you can see I'm using a static `unordered_map` to store a "dictionary" of possible punctuators and then using this map to check if a given string represents a punctuator or not. I'm initializing the map inside the punctuator.c file here:

```
#include "punctuator.h"

std::unordered_map<std::string, PunctuatorEnum> Punctuator::dictionary = {
    { "{", PunctuatorEnum::OPEN_BRACE },
    { "}", PunctuatorEnum::CLOSE_BRACE },
    { ".", PunctuatorEnum::TERMINATOR },
    { "=", PunctuatorEnum::EQUAL },
    { "+", PunctuatorEnum::PLUS },
    { "-", PunctuatorEnum::MINUS },
    { "*", PunctuatorEnum::MULTIPLY },
    { "/", PunctuatorEnum::DIVIDE }
};

Punctuator::Punctuator(std::string lexeme) : ReservedComponent(lexeme) {
    this->punctuator_enum = dictionary.at(lexeme);
}

Punctuator::Punctuator(Punctuator&& punctuator) : ReservedComponent(std::move(punctuator)) {
    this->punctuator_enum = std::move(punctuator.punctuator_enum);
}

bool Punctuator::IsPunctuator(std::string buffer) {
    return dictionary.contains(buffer);
}

PunctuatorEnum Punctuator::ForLexeme(std::string lexeme) {
    return dictionary.at(lexeme);
}
```

I understand this is not the cleanest approach as this forces me to maintain the `PunctuatorEnum` and the unordered map, but it's what I've chosen so far. I'd also like to implement a method `StartsPunctuator(char c)` to check whether a given char starts a punctuator.

My question is as follows: Is it possible to declare a static `unordered_set` variable in my `Punctuator` class, say `punctuator_first_char`, and have it initialized to store only the first chars of every entry of the key-set of the static member variable `dictionary`? This way I would be able to simply call the `contains` method on `punctuator_first_char` in my `StartsPunctuator(char ch)` method without having to iterate through `dictionary`.

Comment: All your punctuators have only one `char` so couldn't you make it `static std::unordered_map<char, PunctuatorEnum> dictionary;` ? Then `dictionary.contains` would work too

Comment: @TedLyngmo At this point yes, but once I add other operators (for example, comparison operators), I'll just run into the same problem.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare a `static unordered_set` variable in my `Punctuator` class, say `punctuator_first_char`, and have it initialized to store only the first chars of every entry of the key-set of the static member variable `dictionary`?

Yes:

```cpp
#include <unordered_set> 

class Punctuator : public ReservedComponent {
   //...
private:
    PunctuatorEnum punctuator_enum;
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, PunctuatorEnum> dictionary;
    static std::unordered_set<char> punctuator_first_char;
};
```

Initialization:

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::inserter

std::unordered_map<std::string, PunctuatorEnum> Punctuator::dictionary = { ... };

std::unordered_set<char> Punctuator::punctuator_first_char = [] {
    std::unordered_set<char> rv;
    std::transform(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(),
                   std::inserter(rv, rv.end()),
                   [](auto&& str_punctenum) { return str_punctenum.first[0]; });
    return rv;
}();
```